# Archiving VMware images on ESXi

Tags: vmware, archive, esxi

Is there a way to compress a VMWare image on a ESXi server for archival purposes?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to do the compression on the server itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with simply using your faviourite archiver/compressor utility?

Answer (score 1):

veeam fastscp to copy it to your management station. after that treat as you like...

Answer (score 0):

I concur with [@Sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148999/archiving-vmware-images-on-esxi#149059) - I use .tar.gz or .tar.bz2.